# Why is Numpy's LinAlg Norm function named the way it is?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have been following some online tutorials that introduce Linear Algebra through Python and have come across the section that talks about a vector's magnitude and normalization. The linear algebra concept seems to state that:

**Magnitude of Vector** = Square all of the elements of a vector, add them together, and take the square root.

**Normalization of Vector** = Divide the vector by the magnitude (or multiply by 1/magnitude).

Great! I attempted to Google for how to find the magnitude of a vector through Numpy's library functions and found that to find the magnitude I am using the [numpy.linalg.norm()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) function. This seemed odd to me at first, but after digging deeper it seems that by default the function finds the Frobenius norm which is essentially finding the magnitude like I did above.

However, I am still unsure why the "normalization" function does not have the option of giving me the normalization of the vector and instead opts to have itself be a "magnitude" function by default. Is there a specific reason why there was not a standalone magnitude function made and instead it resides inside of the norm function? I assume there must be a good reason, but it just seems confusing to me :).

Comment: `norm` is not the "normalization function".  It is the *norm* function; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: Embarrassingly simple, thank you :).

Answer (score 2):

As you already can see in the docs of [numpy.linalg.norm()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), there is a parameter called ord, which is the order of the norm, by default such parameter is None and if you read the docs that means it will be calculating the Frobenius norm, also known as Euclidean distance.

The Frobenius norm is just a **particular case** of the more general concept of  [vector norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html), therefore the numpy's function name norm makes sense by definition.